# separate date from time when exporting table in laravel 5.3 using "maatwebsite/excel": "2.1"

Tags: php, mysql, excel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

When i export data from my table to excel file, in the date section i am getting date plus time in the following format:

```
2016-09-02 00:00:00
```

but i want the date section to display the date only like this for example:

```
2016-09-02
```

Without time.

Here is my code that exports table data to the excel sheet.

```
public function export_records(){
    $date = Carbon::today()->toDateString();

    $nc24_export = nc24form_model::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->get();
    Excel::create('Weekly Report' . $date , function($excel) use($nc24_export){
        $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($nc24_export){
            $sheet->fromArray($nc24_export);

        });
    })->export('xlsx');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sheet->setColumnFormat(['A'=>'@']);
```

try it